# Installing Bazel on databricks cluster

Tags: databricks, bazel

I am new to azure databricks and I want to install a library on a cluster and to do that I need to install bazel build tool first.

I checked the site [bazel](https://bazel.build/install) but I am still not sure how to do it in databricks?

I appriciate if any can help me and write me some steps

Comment: You should have a VM with linux and follow the installation from [here](https://bazel.build/install) and try [databricks](https://github.com/acqio/rules_databricks) rules to execute it.